# Android WebView <input type="file" /> does not honor file extension filter in accept attribute

Tags: android, file, android-webview, filepicker

I have an app with frontend UI being HTML inside WebView. The app lets user pick files for processing. However the following code would not work:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".cbz,.epub,.txt" />
```

All files are greyed out even if they have the correct extension (`childrens-literature.epub` should be pickable):

[image]

I have tested with Edge Chromium and Chrome browser on Codepen and this issue doesn't happen so I conclude it happens to Chromium WebView only. It also happens on both Emulator and real Android 13 device. The same code works for Apple iOS WebView though.

Working alternative is to specify MIME types but this is not possible if certain file extension does not have a popular MIME types (like `.cbz`, ):

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/epub+zip,text/plain" />
```

I cannot find any bug report regarding this. Did I do something wrong? Is there any workaround? If this is a bug, where should I report it?

---

After some further tests, I found out:

- Mixing extensions and MIME types like below code result in only the MIME types being accepted (`.txt` files can be selected but not `.epub`):

```html
<input type="file" accept=".epub,text/plain" />
```

- A single extension would not even work, **so now I found out the problem is that the WebView simply doesn't honor file extension filter at all**

```html
<input type="file" accept=".epub" />
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your WebView does not have settings for working with files in general?

Comment: @BuratinoApps I can pick files I use MIME types instead so it should not be the cause. See what I have tried above.

Comment: Change your webview settings